# Trouble understanding Sylow's Third Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

The statement of Sylow's third theorem in my text goes like this,

Let p be a prime and let G be a group of order $p^km$, where $p$ does not divide $m$. Then the number $n$ of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $g$ is equal to $1$ modulo $p$ and divides $m$. Furthermore, any two Sylow p-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate.

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how the counting part works.

If for example I take the symmetric group of permutations on $3$ elements, this is a group of order $6$. I can write $6 = 2 \cdot 3$, and since $2$ is the largest power of $2$ that divides six, my Sylow 2-subgroups also have order $2$. Now I want to use the theorem to find the number of them.

Now I'm having trouble understanding how the theorem works. I know there are three subgroups of order $2$ in $S_3$, and $3$ mod $2$ is equal to 1 and $3$ divides $m$, but of course $1$ mod $2$ is also equal to $1$ and $1$ divides $m$. So how am I supposed to choose between $1$ and $3$? The statement doesn't seem to mention anything about picking a maximum power or anything like that.

Comment: The statement doesn't give you the number, it just gives pretty strong conditions on it. After all $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ also has order $6$, and only has one $2$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: Oh I see, I must have read more into the theorem when looking at the examples than what the theorem actually said. Thanks! Silly mistake on my part but I'm glad you pointed that out.